# Why am I get the following error "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I am trying to assign the date property of a UIDatePicker to a variable of type Date. I get the error:-

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

Here is the code in question:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class AddPayDateViewController: UIViewController {

    let realm = try! Realm()
    var selectedDate = Date()
    @IBOutlet weak var myDatePicker: UIDatePicker!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func datePickerDateChanged(_ sender: Any) {

        selectedDate = myDatePicker.date
        print("The date selected is \(myDatePicker.date)")

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you linked the `UIDatePicker` from interface builder to `myDatePicker` - double check, do this all the time 

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try

```
if let date = myDatePicker.date {

    self.selectedDate = date 

}
```